Apache performance tuning for high traffic with MPM Event or MPM Prefork?
Hi i want to make some tuning on my new server, i tested with mpm_prefork and mpm_event and i didn't saw high differences..maybe I didn't tune correctly ?
Server:
Ampere® Altra® Q80-30CPU 80 cores / 80 threads @ 3 GHzGeneration:
Altra RAM 128 GB ECC DDR4 RAMDrives
2 x 960 GB NVMe SSD Datacenter
I tried with mpm_prefork.conf:
StartServers             80
MinSpareServers          80
MaxSpareServers          160
MaxRequestWorkers        2048
MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000

And results:


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.62
Server Hostname:        domain.ro
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.3,TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,256,256
Server Temp Key:        X25519 253 bits
TLS Server Name:        domain.ro

Document Path:          /?test
Document Length:        191593 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   129.353 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        820
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 820, Exceptions: 0)
Non-2xx responses:      18
Total transferred:      1920480412 bytes
HTML transferred:       1912529124 bytes
Requests per second:    **77.31** [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1293.531 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       12.935 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          14498.83 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        2    6  42.0      3    1222
Processing:     3 1273 193.8   1252    2190
Waiting:        3 1260 192.1   1240    2182
Total:          5 1279 197.5   1258    2519

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1258
  66%   1346
  75%   1401
  80%   1437
  90%   1532
  95%   1619
  98%   1729
  99%   1805
 100%   2519 (longest request)

Then i installed mpm_event.conf:
StartServers             20
MinSpareThreads          25
MaxSpareThreads          90
ThreadLimit              128
MaxRequestWorkers        1500
ServerLimit              2000

AND www.conf
pm.max_children = 2000

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: (min_spare_servers + max_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 200

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.min_spare_servers = 5

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.max_spare_servers = 300

; The number of rate to spawn child processes at once.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: 32
;pm.max_spawn_rate = 32

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 500

RESULT:
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.62
Server Hostname:        domain.ro
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.3,TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,256,256
Server Temp Key:        X25519 253 bits
TLS Server Name:        domain.ro

Document Path:          /?test8
Document Length:        191594 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   129.584 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        790
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 790, Exceptions: 0)
Non-2xx responses:      15
Total transferred:      1921088225 bytes
HTML transferred:       1913105980 bytes
Requests per second:    **77.17** [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1295.843 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       12.958 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          14477.54 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        2    6  49.6      3    1039
Processing:     5 1278 187.6   1259    2005
Waiting:        5 1266 186.0   1248    1993
Total:          8 1284 195.2   1263    2663

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1263
  66%   1344
  75%   1400
  80%   1434
  90%   1535
  95%   1620
  98%   1721
  99%   1797
 100%   2663 (longest request)





I'm not really certain this is a good fit for SO, maybe Server Fault? Even then, it would help for you to have before and after config changes, visually closer together somehow, along with metric(s) you expected to change and what results did or didn't.

After alot of testing, i found the best solution for 80 core and 128 gb ram server:
StartServers                80
MinSpareThreads             25
MaxSpareThreads             75
ThreadLimit                 128
ThreadsPerChild             128
MaxRequestWorkers           2048
MaxConnectionsPerChild      0

ab test with -c 10000 -n 100 i obtained 808 req/sec :D
